# Как сравнить строку не по байтам а символам?

Tags: php

есть форма ввода, и есть 2 массива с алфавитами

```
  $pl = ['a','ą','b','c','ć','d','e','ę','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','ł','m','n','ń','o','ó','p','r','s','ś','t','u','w','y','z','ź,','ż'];

$pl16 = ['m','n','ń','o','ó','p','r','s','ś','t','u','w','y','z','ź,','ż','a','ą','b','c','ć','d','e','ę','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','ł'];
```

нужно сделать кодировку вида rot16, если я ввожу английские символы то работает отлично, все выводит, но если я в форму ввиду букву такого вида `ą` , то уже не работает. Так как буква польского алфавита состоит из 2х байтов. Как мне достать каждый символ по очереди? и заменить его? вот эта функция

```
function rot16($str){

$rot16 = '';

    for($i = 0; $i < strlen($str); $i++){
       for ($j = 0; $j < count($pl); $j++) 
       { 
          if ($str[$i] == $pl[$j]){
            $res = str_replace($str[$i], $pl16[$j],$str[$i]);
          }
       }        
       $rot16 .= $res;
    }
return $rot16;
```

}

массивы находятся в функции, и $str это входная строка из формы. Нужно вместо `$str[$i] == $pl[$j]` как то сравнить каждый символ строки, а не байт.

Comment: Попробуйте регуляркой. `[ваши символы]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте почитать мануалы - в пыхе много интересного ) Вариант Вашей функции:

```
define('DICT', array_combine($pl, $pl16));

function rot16($str) {
    return strtr($str, DICT);
}
```

Comment: Огромнейшее спасибо! Это просто взрыв мозга) Я и не думал, что это можно сделать настолько просто) Вот только я не совсем понимаю как работает функция `strtr()` ? она просматривает строку и если находит в массиве подобный ключ, то заменяет эту строку на значения из ключа?

Comment: @AntonKucenko тут всё подробно написано: [strtr()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.strtr.php)